# Get the content of a cell having formula using excel

Tags: excel, data-driven-tests

I want to get content of a cell in Excel whose value is calculated using a Formula (=D6*0.1236) and i am using HssfWorkbook and using getCell() method to get content. But i am getting D6*0.1236. I want to get the value calculated using this formula and not the formula. Please suggest some solution for this.

Below is the code to get the contents

```
     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
     Row r = sheet.getRow(13);
     //get the cell [a particular cell of the row obtained above]
     Cell c = r.getCell(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not suppose to use getCell() to fetch a value. Try the following ,

```
Cell c = r.getCell(2);
System.out.println("The Cell value is " + c.getNumericCellValue());
```

Comment: @Niki, Feel free to Upvote and accept the answer if that is what your are looking for( this is what we do it in StackOverflow , since you are new to the community ;)